# When emulating vim within a Python Subprocess, my program will print over my vim instance. How do I stop this?

Tags: python-3.x, vim, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, tmux

When I run vim in a subprocess, I have the script that created that subprocess continue printing miscellaneous status updates. However the updates get printed on top of my vim instance. How do I create a behavior where I only see the output when I quit vim (:q).

I'm running the subprocess like this:

```
def callVim():
    # Open the file with the text editor
    EDITOR = os.environ.get('EDITOR','vim')
    call([EDITOR, temp_loc])

try:
    print('Starting vim process...')
    vim = Process(target = callVim)
    vim.start()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Terminating vim server.")
    vim.terminate()
    vim.join()
```

And this is what the overlaid output looks like ('Check if target updated...' being the output):

[image: vim with python print statements in top]

Thank you for any and all help.

Any kind of suggestion is welcome.

I'm running tmux if that matters?

EDIT:
So i tried rerouting the sys.stdout to a variable before calling on vim, like so:

```
so = sys.stdout = StringIO()
EDITOR = os.environ.get('EDITOR','vim')
call([EDITOR, self.temp_loc])
```

But it still printed over vim.

EDIT2:
Also I need to keep the output somewhere because i use it elsewhere in the program.

Comment: You cant both use the screen at the same time. Write to a logfile?

Comment: I just tried rerouting sys.stdout to a variable but that didn't work. Is that what you were saying?

Comment: Maybe when running the subprocess in vim append to your command  `> /dev/null` to pipe the output to nothing.

Comment: More importantly, why are you doing this? Python subprocess does NOT work well with interactive bash programs like vim

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble. I tried the logging module and writing that to a file. I think that's what I needed. Thanks!